# Ozone cross-section in the near-infrared

Tags: ir-spectroscopy, ozone

I am searching for ozone absorption cross-section in the wavelengths range 1.1 μm to 10 μm. So far I looked in the following databases:

- [HITRAN](https://hitran.org/)
- [Max-Planck Institute for Chemistry Mainz](http://satellite.mpic.de/spectral_atlas/)

and of course, googled it.
Any idea where I can find such information?

Comment: By searching for ozone ir absorption I found this http://vpl.astro.washington.edu/spectra/o3.htm which gives hitran spectra  over several spectral ranges.